# How to bridge Swift String to Objective C NSString?

Tags: ios, string, swift

Am I taking crazy pills? Directly out of the documentation:

> “Swift automatically bridges between the String type and the NSString class. This means that anywhere you use an NSString object, you can use a Swift String type instead and gain the benefits of both types—the String type’s interpolation and Swift-designed APIs and the NSString class’s broad functionality. For this reason, you should almost never need to use the NSString class directly in your own code. In fact, when Swift imports Objective-C APIs, it replaces all of the NSString types with String types. When your Objective-C code uses a Swift class, the importer replaces all of the String types with NSString in imported API.

To enable string bridging, just import Foundation.”

**I've done this... consider:**

```
import Foundation

var str = "Hello World"

var range = str.rangeOfString("e")

// returns error: String does not contain member named: rangeOfString()
```

**However:**

```
var str = "Hello World" as NSString

var range = str.rangeOfString("e")

// returns correct (2, 1)
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: Actually the first case shouldn't return an error. It should be {Some "1..<2"}

Comment: The second one should return (1,1)

Comment: Im not making it up... It will not work

Comment: Your right it does return (1,1) :-) However I guess I am not understanding the point of needing to cast it to NSString.

Comment: Which Xcode versions are you using? *Both* your code samples compile in Xcode 6.1.1 and in 6.3 beta.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You already have the answer in your question. You're missing the cast. When writing Swift code, a statement such as this one

```
var str = "Hello World"
```

creates a Swift `String`, not an `NSString`. To make it work as an `NSString`, you should cast it to an `NSString` using the `as` operator before using it.

This is different than calling a method written in Objective-C and supplying a `String` instead of an `NSString` as a parameter.

Comment: I guess my question is that the documentation makes it sound like it automatically bridges between NSString and String not requiring a cast. Am I reading the documentation wrong?

Comment: Pay attention to this part. `When Swift imports Objective-C APIs, it replaces all of the NSString types with String types. When your Objective-C code uses a Swift class, the importer replaces all of the String types with NSString in imported API.` This means that you can supply a swift `String` to a method that requires an `NSString`, or vice-versa. It doesn't mean that you can create a swift `String` and use it as if it was a `NSString` variable everywhere.

Comment: @Bren Swift will automatically bridge if you pass a `String` to a method that takes an `NSString`. But it will not add `NSString`'s methods to `String` itself. This automatic bridging is also removed in Swift 1.2.

Comment: Thank you for helping me... that makes sense. I am using Xcode 6.1.1. Casting works just fine. @CihanTek Thank you for explaining that part to me. I was definitely misunderstanding what the "bridging" accomplished.

Comment: For me it compiles in Xcode 6.1.1 even without the cast to NSString.

Comment: As a side note to this answer, objc's NSRange is not bridged to Swift's Range<Int>.

Answer (score 32):

To go from `String` to `NSString` use the following constructor:

```
let swiftString:String = "I'm a string."
let objCString:NSString = NSString(string:swiftString)
```

**With Xcode 7 (beta)**, using a downcast from `String` to `NSString`, as in below example, will result in a warning message, **Cast from 'String?' to unrelated type 'NSString' always fails**:

```
let objcString:NSString = swiftString as! NSString // results in error
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is example for this :

```
string str_simple = "HELLO WORLD";

//string to NSString
NSString *stringinObjC = [NSString stringWithCString:str_simple.c_str()
                                encoding:[NSString defaultCStringEncoding]];            
NSLog(stringinObjC);
```

Comment: You convert a UTF string to ASCII and back and thus, this will only work with ASCII characters which may result in a nasty error later.